Pyrogram cannot receive message from forwarded bot message
I want to forward a message from multiple channels to another channel. For some reason, I cannot receive a message coming from another bot channel. My goal is to relay a message from a public channel that sends a signal to buy and sell crypto to my own channel.
I've attached some of the code generated by ChatGPT.
I can send a message from channelA and it will receive and copy it to channelB. But on the on_message on the channelB, I didn't get any message. I have tried other public channels as well that seem using bot to send the message and I didn't receive on_message from those channels.
How can I fix this?
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize Pyrogram client
app = Client("my_account")

# Channel usernames or IDs
channelA = 'channelA'
channelB = 'channelB'
channelC = 'channelC'

# Forward messages from ChannelA to ChannelB
@app.on_message(filters.chat(channelA))
def forward_to_channelB(client, message):
    logging.info(f"Forwarding message from ChannelA: {message.text}")
    message.copy(channelB)  # Copy message to ChannelB

# Forward messages from ChannelB to ChannelC, including those sent by the bot
@app.on_message(filters.chat(channelB))
def forward_to_channelC(client, message):
    logging.info(f"Forwarding message from ChannelB: {message.text}")

app.run()

I have tried reading all the message like this but if it's coming from a bot channel it cannot receive any message.
@app.on_message()
def readMsg(client, message):
    logging.info(f"Fo`your text`rwarding message: {message.text}")

I can't seems to find related question regarding this but I've also try to use on_raw_update and it also don't show any message. Some other question suggest that it might cause because the channel doesn't allow copy or forward but it isn't the case on mine. My guess is because the message is coming from other mtproto copy function. But anybody encounter this and have any suggestion?

maybe it's the channel settings like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70509473/pyrogram-mtproto-to-read-and-copy-telegram-messages. Can you forward a message from ChannelA to channelB manually?

I can manually forward message from A to B and B to C manually.. because of that i don’t think because of restricted copy. I’ve also created my own public channel and not getting message from ChannelB if it’s a copied message from ChannelA.

There is no message.copy() within the forward_to_channelC function, perhaps ChatGpt didnt include that in that function?
You can also check how I implemented a bit of a different approach lines 172:183 where I download the message content, and then upload the message content bypassing all sorts of restrictions.

whoops, I forgot to add the copy, but regardless I don't get the logging info on the forward_to_channelC function. I've tried another approach using telethon and it's working fine now. I'll try your implementation too and check whether it's a library issue or maybe my networking VPS issue (Previously I was using e2-micro on GCP and now I use VPS from Racknerd). I haven't got time to debug it again properly. Thanks, guys.
